# Update a label in tkinter from a button press

Tags: python, tkinter

My question is regarding GUI programming in python by using tkinter. I believe this is Python 3x.

My question: While we're executing a program to run the GUI, can a button update a label? More specifically, is there a way to change the labels displayed text after pushing the button? I have consulted stack overflow on this before and adopted the StringVar() method, but it doesn't seem to fix my problem, in fact it omits the text from the GUI completely!

Here is the code below

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Copy Text GUI Program')

copiedtext = StringVar()
copiedtext.set("Text is displayed here")


def copytext():
    copiedtext.set(textentered.get())

# Write 'Enter Text Here'
entertextLabel = Label(root, text="Enter Text Here")
entertextLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

# For the user to write text into the gui
textentered = Entry(root)
textentered.grid(row=0, column=1)

# The Copy Text Button
copytextButton = Button(root, text="Copy Text")
copytextButton.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)

# Display the copied text
displaytextLabel = Label(root, textvariable=copiedtext)
displaytextLabel.grid(row=2,columnspan=2)


copytextButton.configure(command=copytext())

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also as an amendment to my question, when I wrote text instead of textvariable for displaytextLabel, it output some PY-4060 (I assume this is memory, not sure) so I know that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to bind a Button event to the copytextButton object like so:

```
copytextButton.bind('<Button-1>', copytext)
```

This means that a callback function - copytext() will be called when you left-click the button.

A slight modification is needed in the function itself, since the callback sends an event argument:

```
def copytext(event):
    copiedtext.set(textentered.get())
```

Edit:
This line is not needed:

```
copytextButton.configure(command=copytext())
```

Comment: Thank You so much, it is working now ! Is there any reason why the bind function is better to use here instead of the configure function?

Comment: You did not assign the function to command in `configure`, but assign the result of function `copytext`.  You should use `copytextButton.configure(command=copytext)`.

Comment: @acw1668 is correct, the best solution is to just remove the parenthesis (I missed this as well).